# Create modified Subsites using CSOM C# or PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, visual-studio, csom, sub-site

I am currently looking into solutions to optimize the create subsite function within SharePoint Online. I would like to have my SharePoint clients fill in a form or list with several configuration details for the creation of the subsite including the **logo** which preferably gets automatically applied to the site. Is there also an possibility to add Term sets to SharePoint based on the given input?

To sum it all up i would like to create/modify the subsite creation process:

1. User gets a form/list in which he has to give input needed for Site creation (Title, URL) and a possibility to upload a logo image.
2. Subsite gets created with the input from above. The uploaded logo image gets applied to the site.
3. Input from above gets added to existing term sets, or new term sets are created based upon the input given.